# Trouble with a function inside of a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I've created a set of objects:

```
rs_s = {
rs_s_72 <- regular_season %>% filter(season == 72)
rs_s_73 <- regular_season %>% filter(season == 73)
rs_s_74 <- regular_season %>% filter(season == 74)
rs_s_75 <- regular_season %>% filter(season == 75)
rs_s_76 <- regular_season %>% filter(season == 76)
rs_s_77 <- regular_season %>% filter(season == 77)
rs_s_78 <- regular_season %>% filter(season == 78)
rs_s_79 <- regular_season %>% filter(season == 79)
rs_s_80 <- regular_season %>% filter(season == 80)
rs_s_81 <- regular_season %>% filter(season == 81)
rs_s_82 <- regular_season %>% filter(season == 82)
rs_s_83 <- regular_season %>% filter(season == 83)
rs_s_84 <- regular_season %>% filter(season == 84)
rs_s_85 <- regular_season %>% filter(season == 85)
}
```

I then tried to take the mean of the "correct" column within each object with this code, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
for (i in rs_s){
 mean('correct')
  print(mean)
}
```

If someone knows, could someone tell me where I might have gone wrong, and how I could fix it?

EDIT: I have also looked at several other questions on this site and other sites but none have seemed especially pertinent to this question.

Comment: Hey @akrun Thanks for your comment - do you know how I might phrase it better syntactically?

Comment: Based on the syntax showed, you are creating multiple objects in the global env.  i.e. `rs_s_72`, `rs_s_73` etc.  The `rs_s = {.` is not making sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we have created objects that starts with 'rs_s_' in the global env, get those objects based on the pattern with `mget` into a `list`, extract the `correct` column and get the `mean` by looping over the `list` with `sapply`

```
sapply(mget(ls(pattern = '^rs_s_\\d+$')), function(x) mean(x$correct))
```

---

Based on the syntax, it may be better to do a group_by with 'season' instead of `filter`ing, thus avoiding the step of creating multiple objects, then gathering those objects to calculate the `mean`

```
library(dplyr)
regular_season %>%
    group_by(season) %>%
    summarise(Mean = mean(correct, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')
```

---

If we need only the `mean` for particular 'season', then do the `filter` before the `group_by`

```
regular_season %>%
   filter(season %in% 72:85) %>%
   group_by(season) %>%
   summarise(Mean = mean(correct, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')
```